# How can I order an inference result using bnlearn in Python?

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, pgmpy

So, I'm using the Python bnlearn package and when you make the inference a table with probabilistic data is returned. The problem is that I have a lot of data and it would be more interesting if the table were ordered descending. I have no idea how to manipulate that. The class of the 'table' is pgmpy.factors.discrete.DiscreteFactor.DiscreteFactor.

[This is how the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBe10.png)

Is it possible to manipulate?

Answer (score 0):

The source code of  [pgmpy.factors.discrete.DiscreteFactor.DiscreteFactor](https://pgmpy.org/_modules/pgmpy/factors/discrete/DiscreteFactor.html) indicates that the possible values of the variable are stored in the `state_names` member dictionary, and the actual probabilities in the `values` member as a numpy array. You can order with a clause similar to

```
sorted(zip(your_discrete_factor_object.state_names["your variable name"], your_discrete_factor_object.values.tolist()), key = lambda p: p[1])
```